# y-axis scale limits not working when using ggplot() in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have two `ggplot()` graphs `p1` and `p2` that I'm displaying next to each other. For that reason, I would like both to have the same `ylim()`. Here's the script I'm using for `p1`:

```
p1<-ggplot(data = dfnew, aes(x = Time, y = Proportion, group=linegroup)) +
  geom_point(aes(shape = as.character(Collar)), size = 4, stroke = 0, 
             position = myjit)+
  geom_line(aes(group = linegroup),linetype = "dotted",size=1, position = myjit) +
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=15),
        axis.title=element_text(size=20)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = Lower, ymax = Upper), width=0.3, size=1,
                position = myjit) + scale_shape_manual(values=c("41361´"=19,"41366´"=15)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("Day" = "black", 
                                "Night" = "black")) + 
  labs(shape="Collar ID") + 
  ylim(0.05, 0.4) + theme(legend.position = "none")+ 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(n = 5))+
  ggtitle("Feeding")
```

And here's the script I'm using for `p2`:

```
p2<-ggplot(data = dfnew, aes(x = Area, y = Proportion,colour=Area, group=linegroup)) +
  geom_point(aes(shape = as.character(Collar)), size = 4, stroke = 0, 
             position = myjit)+
  geom_line(aes(group = linegroup),linetype = "dotted",size=1, position = myjit) +
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=15),
        axis.title=element_text(size=20)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = Lower, ymax = Upper), width=0.3, size=1,
                position = myjit) + scale_shape_manual(values=c("41361´"=19,"41365´"=17)) + scale_size_manual(values=c(2,2)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("SNP" = "brown", 
                                "LGCA" = "darkgoldenrod2")) + labs(shape="Collar ID") + 
  ylim(0.05, 0.4) +
  theme(legend.text=element_text(size=18))+
  theme(legend.title = element_text(size=18)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(n = 5))+
  ggtitle(" ") + theme(legend.position = "none")
```

However, as seen on the image below, y axis don't match. Not only that, but even when specifying `scale_y_continuous(breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(n = 5))` I don't get the same number of tick in both y axis:
[image]

Hope at least somebody can set me on the right track, in case this is fixable. If it helps, I used the following data for `p1`:

```
> dput(dfnew)
structure(list(Proportion = c(0.242, 0.216, 0.29, 0.256), Lower = c(0.173, 
0.152, 0.214, 0.186), Upper = c(0.329, 0.296, 0.381, 0.342), 
    Time = c("Day", "Night", "Day", "Night"), Collar = c("41361´", 
    "41361´", "41366´", "41366´"), ymin = c(0.069, 0.064, 0.076, 
    0.07), ymax = c(0.571, 0.512, 0.671, 0.598), linegroup = c("Day 41361´", 
    "Night 41361´", "Day 41366´", "Night 41366´")), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

and for `p2`:

```
> dput(dfnew)
structure(list(Proportion = c(0.181, 0.289, 0.099, 0.224), Lower = c(0.148, 
0.242, 0.096, 0.217), Upper = c(0.219, 0.341, 0.104, 0.232), 
    Area = c("LGCA", "SNP", "LGCA", "SNP"), Collar = c("41361´", 
    "41361´", "41365´", "41365´"), ymin = c(0.033, 0.047, 0.003, 
    0.00700000000000001), ymax = c(0.4, 0.63, 0.203, 0.456), 
    linegroup = c("LGCA 41361´", "SNP 41361´", "LGCA 41365´", 
    "SNP 41365´")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: a quick workaround might be to add a column e.g. `group` for time / area, row bind your two data.frames together and do one plot with a `facet_wrap( ~group, scales="free_x")` added to guarantee the same y scales on the plots.

Comment: As you are also using a `scale_y_continuous` term, you should probably use a `limits=c(0.05,0.4)` argument in that, rather than using `ylim` as well

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by instead of `ylim()`using `coord_cartesian`like this: `+coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0.05, 0.4), expand = TRUE)`

Comment: I'm getting an error: ```+   coord_cartesian(ylim = (0.05,0.4), expand = TRUE) + theme(legend.position = "none")+ 
Error: unexpected ',' in:
"  labs(shape="Collar ID") + 
  coord_cartesian(ylim = (0.05," ```

Comment: Fixed. It's ```+coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0.05, 0.4), expand = TRUE)``` However, once I do this how do I change the number of ticks in the y axis?

Comment: Sorry I missed the c()! For ticks you should be able to keep your `scale_y_continuous()` as you want to have it